# Python: Calling method inside class gives "unsupported operand type(s)" error

Tags: python, class, object, calculator

Im trying to call the sum function inside my Calculator class, but it gives me the following error:
`unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Calculator'.`
However if i were to use the function outside the class and call it it works fine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

#Solution

```
class Calculator(object):
    
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
    
    def sum(*args): //Change to self
        result = 0

        for arg in args://Change to self.args
            result = result + arg

        return result

t = Calculator(3,4,5)
t.sum()
```

---

**Follow up question; Adding the rest of the operators(/, *, -)**
For multiplication i can basicly use the same syntax

```
def mul(self):
    result = 1
    for arg in self.args:
        result = result * arg
        
    return result
```

The problem occurs for division and subtraction. When the function has to take into account the position of the arguments.

```
def subtract(self):
    result = 0

    for arg in self.args:
        result = arg - result

    return result
```

Calling my function like before;

```
t = Calculator(3,4). 
t.subtract() 
# output 
1 (4 -3)
# wanted output
-1 (3-4)
```

The same goes for division where Calculator(x,y) gives (y/x).

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `self` argument in your method.

```py
class Calculator:
    
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
    
    def sum(self):
        return sum(self.args)
```

Note that you do not have to subclass the `object` class if you are using Python 3. `sum(self.args)` is another simplification you can make.

---

**An answer to the follow up question**

You can use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module.

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator


class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def subtract(self):
        return reduce(operator.sub, self.args[1:], self.args[0])
    
    def divide(self):
        return reduce(operator.truediv, self.args[1:], self.args[0])

print(Calculator(3, 4).subtract())  # -1
print(Calculator(3).subtract())  # 3
print(Calculator(3, 4, 5).subtract())  # -6
print(Calculator(3, 4).divide())  # 0.75
```